# Crash Plan Pro NAS?

Tags: backup

I use ubuntu as my NAS. I was wondering if anyone has crashplan running and backs up automatically from your mac/pc to a ubuntu device running crashplan? Thinking about the future of my backups.

Thanks!

Comment: Crashplan will back up to any attached **drive** or computer via a network regardless of what operating system is running on it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - done with a link for reference

Answer (score 1):

Crashplan will back up to any attached drive or computer via a network regardless of what operating system is running on it.

Have a look at the Crashplan documentation for [Multiple Destination Backup](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/feature/multi_destination_backup)